# laravel 5 distinct query

Tags: laravel-5, distinct

i have two tables one is event_invoice and payments.Here event_invoice is having invoice rows where as payments table will be having the multiple rows for single invoice.Below is the  event_invoice structure

```
    id Eventcode Currency Amount
    1   E032      INR     375400
    2   E032      INR     366740
    3   E032      INR     283250
    4   E034      USD     5000
    5   E034      USD     5500
    6   E034      USD     5000
    7   E034      USD     5500
```

Here is the payments structure

```
invoice_id rcvamount 
1           20000
2           50000
2           50000
3           40000
5           1500
6           5000
```

my left query is as follows

```
DB::table('event_invoice') 
->leftjoin('payments', 'event_invoice.Id', '=', 'payments.invoice_id')->where('event_invoice.Status','=','1')
->where( DB::raw('year(DueDate)'), $year)
->select(DB::raw('

sum(event_invoice.Amount) as invoicevalue,
sum(payments.recieved_amount+payments.adjust_amount)  as recvamount
'))

->groupBy('event_invoice.EventName')->groupBy('event_invoice.CurrencyType')->distinct()
->get();
```

results:

```
eventcode currency invoicevalue 
E032       INR     1392130
E034       USD     21500
```

But the actual results should be like as follows

```
eventcode currency invoicevalue 
    E032       INR     1025390
    E034       USD     21500
```

when i am doing left join query in the payment table that eventcode having two rows in payments table  so its adding two times of that particular invoice to avoid this i have used distinct() but its not working. 
Can you please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Please some one help me out to resolve this issue ..Thank youu

Comment: You can also run the `raw` query. Write the `raw sql` query and try to run. It may be solve your problem.

Comment: even have run the mysql in the database like as follows using :

Comment: SELECT sum(Amount) 
FROM event_invoice 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.invoice_id = event_invoice.Id
WHERE event_invoice.Status = '1' and event_invoice.Eventcode='E032' and event_invoice.CurrencyType='INR' and year(DueDate)='2016'

Comment: That's not solve your problem?

Comment: if i use distinct for the amount in the query for one event its giving correct other one its giving wrong .what to do please help me.

Comment: no i did not ..please give some idea to solve this

Comment: You know the meaning of the `Join`, `Left Join` and `Right Join` and `Full join` It too much completed to implement the query. I personally suggest you can try like this `SELECT Eventcode,sum(Amount) FROM event_invoice group by Currency;` It's easy to understand..

Comment: If you want some more data or data in specific format that describe me I will try to implement this.

Comment: I also created the online fiddle for you try here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f29a/3

Comment: But i want to calculate rcv amount from payments table .For that i have to write another query how can i match two tables..?

Comment: As per my knowledge, You must be create the single record for single event in invoice table. If you are creating multiple invoice record for the same event that's not good idea, You can update the record if any new invoice in same event. And user may pay invoice in multiple time so, its okay if you are creating the multiple record in payments table. If you implement this technique so you can fire following query to achieve what you want:

Comment: `SELECT event_invoice.Eventcode, Amount,sum(rcvamount),Currency FROM event_invoice LEFT JOIN payments on event_invoice.Eventcode=payments.Eventcode where event_invoice.Eventcode=payments.Eventcode group by Currency;`

Comment: @KalpeshRajai i have created only one record in event_invoice table .but for that invoice there will be multiple rows of receivable payments .in that case in join query the amount of invoice is adding twice.

Comment: Check online demo here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ac8d/1 I already implemented this. It works as you said.

Comment: Link itself is not opening @KalpeshRajai